# Trato de accesar los nodos hijo del body de un html. Sin embargo, el primer y único hijo que aparece es DOCTYPE!

Tags: javascript

He tratado de acceder al body usando:

1. document.body
2. document.documentElement.body
3. document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]
4. document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
5. document.getElementById('body'); // Le he puesto un id al body

En el body, he puesto siete `<h1>` solamente para probar.

En todas, usando ya sea .childElementCount o .children.length, retorna sólo un hijo, y ni si quiera es un `<h1>`, sino me retorna el DOCTYPE!. Les pego el código con el que he descubierto esto:

```js
var padre = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
console.log("Probando el padre.childElementCount, da como resultado: " + padre.childElementCount);
console.log("Y toma el " + padre.children[0].tagName + " como hijo");
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Título 1</h1>
  <h1>Título 2</h1>
  <h1>Título 3</h1>
  <h1>Título 4</h1>
  <h1>Título 5</h1>
</body>
```

Y lo que obtengo en consola de Chrome, es:

```
prueba.js:69       Sólo el body es el padre
prueba.js:71       Probando el padre.children.count, da como resultado: 1
prueba.js:72       Y toma el DOCTYPE! como hijo
```

Comment: Me ha eliminado algunas palabras. Aquí está arreglado:

Comment: En el body, he puesto siete h1 solamente para probar.

En todas, usando ya sea .childElementCount o .children.length, retorna sólo un hijo, y ni si quiera es un h1, sino me retorna el DOCTYPE!. Les pego el código con el que he descubierto esto:

Comment: getElementById se usa cuando le agregas a una etiqueta id al tag , primero como esta tu HTML presiento que esta mal formado , realice la prueba y me funciona muy bien

Comment: Acabo de poner tu código como ejecutable y parece funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Mil gracias a ambos. Lo de la etiqueta id al tag es verdad, y la probe sin éxito también. Mi html es:

<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  <title>Prueba </title>
  <script id="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="prueba.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 id="datos">T&IacuteTULO</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="datos2">T&IacuteTULO</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="datos3">T&IacuteTULO</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="datos4">T&IacuteTULO</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="datos5">T&IacuteTULO</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="datos6">T&IacuteTULO</h1>
  <hr>
  <h1 id="datos7">T&IacuteTULO</h1>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Como nota: no es `<DOCTYPE! html>` debería ser `<!doctype html>` con el `!` delante de doctype y no detrás. Eso puede crearte el problema porque se interpretará como una etiqueta normal y no como una declaración. Si al cambiar eso se solucionara el problema, deberías cerrar/borrar la pregunta porque sería un simple fallo tipográfico.

Comment: Ya veo. Precisamente eso solucionó el error. Mil gracias por su ayuda. Sí ha sido un error hasta cierto punto inocente por no decir descuidado. Mil gracias de nuevo. Todo está solucionado.

Saludos

Comment: @ChrisN. Me alegra que te sirviera. Voy a cerrar la pregunta como no relacionada por ser un fallo tipográfico.

Comment: Sin problema alguno. Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba utilizando jQuery. En mi ejemplo utilizare h5 por que el texto de h1 abarca demasiado espacio

```js
function recorrer_body(){
  var hijos = $("body").children("h5"); //Esto retorna todos los del body con etiqueta <h1>
  var texto = "";
  
  for(i=0; i<hijos.length; i++){
    texto += $(hijos[i]).text()+"\n";
  }
  alert(texto);
  $("#resultado").val(texto); //Aqui imprimos el resultado en el textarea
}
```

```html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Título de la página</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <h5>numero 1</h5>
        <h5>numero 2</h5>
        <h5>numero 3</h5>
        <h5>numero 4</h5>
        
        <textarea id="resultado"></textarea><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="recorrer_body()">Recorrer body</button>
    </BODY>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</HTML>
```

sino se comprende muy bien, te dejo la página que me sirvió a mi...

http://michelletorres.mx/padres-hijos-y-hermanos-en-jquery/

Comment: Mil gracias por tu respuesta. Ciertamente prefiero puro JavaScript, aunque podría utilizar la sugerencia. Muchas gracias, saludos.

Comment: De nada, me alegra que tu problema fuera resuelto, suerte